# Can more exercise alter human genes?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, humans

I want to know if exercise can change genes or not, if yes then what is process behind it and is it permanent or temporarily.

Comment: Yes. The science that study how the genes change due to outside factors is called Epigenetics.

Comment: Since you seem to have researches answering your question, what are you exactly asking us?

Comment: i didn't research at first i search "myriad of epigenetic changes" ans given by AngelPray. either way like i said we don't know those articles are authenticate or not , do we

Comment: @earthling The article linked by Angel Pray is well referenced from many reputable sources of world-class research. What about it do you think is not "authentic"?

Comment: Challenging the authenticity or reputation of an article is not a worldbuilding question.

Comment: @L.Dutch by that logic i can prove everything by posting on my articles

Comment: @Agrajag i m not talking about authenticity of that article

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY [Epigenetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics) ~ the genes don't change ~ the organisms phenotype & the expression of it's genes changes but the genes don't ~ that really is a very different thing from the genes changing ~ the extra muscle mass you put on as a result of weight training could be called epigenetic, but that's got nothing to do with changes to your genes.

Answer (score 5):

Within a single individual, you can't affect the genes themselves, but you can affect the expression of those genes (that is whether/how genes will activate). This is called epigenetics. And indeed, physical exercise causes a [myriad of epigenetic changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics_of_physical_exercise).

Comment: I think by expression you mean mapping of dna Right?

Comment: @earthling What? No. I meant exactly what I said. Expression. I even clarified what this means. Genes possess epigenetic tags that govern whether or not those genes are "expressed", again, that means whether or not/how the genes will activate. You can't change the genes themselves through exercise but you can change the epigenetic tags and thus affect the genes. They'll still be there exactly the same as they were before but they will not "work" in the same way.

Comment: I found section 4 of one of the articles linked in the Wikipedia page particularly interesting: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5705447/#S11title

It discusses how exercise can actually have effects on the offspring of an individual across generations, including reduced chances of diabetes, anxiety and schizophrenia. Very interesting stuff, thanks for the link @AngelPray